# C# large string arrives to WebApi as null

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I'm having an issue with uploading large files (up to 500 mb) from client to server with ASP.NET Web API. The problem occures when uploading file size is larger than 370 mb. Smaller file arrive to Web API without problem, but if the file is larger, i recieve null value parameter at Web API.

The files i am trying to upload are BSON serialized, so it is a string named" poststring", and deserialized at server side.

The BSON serialization also occurs without problem, no mather the size of file at client.

I don't recieve any error, when file is larger it just arrives as null.

Client side of request:

```
HttpWebRequest webRequest = WebRequest.Create(uri) as HttpWebRequest;
webRequest.Method = "POST";     
const string contentType = "application/json";
webRequest.ContentType = contentType;
webRequest.ContentLength = postString.Length;
StreamWriter requestWriter = new StreamWriter(webRequest.GetRequestStream());
requestWriter.Write(postString);          
requestWriter.Close();
StreamReader responseReader = new StreamReader(webRequest.GetResponse().GetResponseStream());
string responseData = responseReader.ReadToEnd();
responseReader.Close();
webRequest.GetResponse().Close();
```

Web API:

```
public void UploadDocuments([FromBody]string aBsonString)
{
   //If aBsonString is larger than 370 mb, the string is null!    
   //CODE
}
```

Things i tried in IIS:

-I had set the maxAllowedContentLength to 2147483648

-I had set the maxRequestLength to 2147483648

I set so large values only for testing, and I will later decrease it, because i know this can be an vulnerability.

Comment: I think you should try to get the input stream from the request and read from it.

Comment: are you getting some error in IIS ? like  404.13 check you check event log

Comment: Yes have you checked the system event log on the server?

Comment: Did you find a solution?